# How can I figure out this Channel Destruct error?

Tags: c#, database, postgresql

**Error Message**

```
Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42883: function cdr.channeldestructed(_cdrid => integer) does not exist
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<>c__DisplayClass159_0.<<DoReadMessage>g__ReadMessageLong|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<>c__DisplayClass159_0.<<DoReadMessage>g__ReadMessageLong|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.<NextResult>d__44.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.<ExecuteReaderAsync>d__101.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.<ExecuteNonQuery>d__92.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at PBXCommon.CDR.dbCDR.ChannelDestructed(Int32 CdrID) in C:\Users\fmurphy\source\repos\CDYNE PBX\PBXCore\PBXCommon\CDR\dbCDR.cs:line 183
   at PBXCore.Channels.Channel.Finalize() in C:\Users\fmurphy\source\repos\CDYNE PBX\PBXCore\PBXCore\Channels\Channel.cs:line 359
  Exception data:
    Severity: ERROR
    SqlState: 42883
    MessageText: function cdr.channeldestructed(_cdrid => integer) does not exist
    Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
    Position: 15
    File: parse_func.c
    Line: 624
    Routine: ParseFuncOrColumn
```

**Code Where Line Errors Exist**

```
public static void ChannelDestructed(int CdrID)
        {
            using (NpgsqlConnection c = PBXCommon.dbCommon.GetNewPostgresConnection())
            {
                c.Open();
                NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("cdr.channeldestructed", c);
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("_cdrid", NpgsqlDbType.Integer).Value = CdrID;
183             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

        }



 ~Channel()
        {
            try
            {
                WeakReference oC;
                ChannelList.AllChannels.TryRemove(ChannelID, out oC);

359             PBXCommon.CDR.dbCDR.ChannelDestructed(CdrID);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                PBXLogging.Log(LoggingLevel.Error, this, "Channel - Destruct Error\r\n{0}", ex);
            }

            PBXLogging.Log(LoggingLevel.Debug, this, "Channel - Destructed");
```

I am an intern trying to figure this problem out for my boss and did not write most of this code. This uses PostgreSQL written in C# for database management.

Comment: "No function matches the given name and argument types." sounds like the stored procedure you're trying to call does not exist. Have you checked if it exists?

Comment: Yes, StoredProcedue = 4; Also, I just found the debug try catch that my boss put in. 
try
            {
                WeakReference oC;
                ChannelList.AllChannels.TryRemove(ChannelID, out oC);

                PBXCommon.CDR.dbCDR.ChannelDestructed(CdrID);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                PBXLogging.Log(LoggingLevel.Error, this, "Channel - Destruct Error\r\n{0}", ex);
            }

            PBXLogging.Log(LoggingLevel.Debug, this, "Channel - Destructed");

Comment: Stored procedures are defined on the database server. It sounds like the function `cdr.channeldestructed` is not available in your database. `StoredProcedue = 4` is not a function definition. To understand stored procedures, this article may help: https://carto.com/help/working-with-data/sql-stored-procedures/

Comment: Thanks for the help! You were right - the function was named differently in our Postgres database and did not get correctly named when we switched over.

Comment: Great. I've posted it as an answer so others can see that this post is solved.

Answer (score 0):

The error message "No function matches the given name and argument types." sounds like the stored procedure `cdr.channeldestructed` is not available in your database.